# Android emulator still slow as hell even with Intel image, why?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've successfully installed the Intel AVM for Jelly Bean v4.1, and I can create and start an Intel x86 AVM. However it's just as slow as the ARM ones. Having wasted a lot of time on this, as far as I can see the Intel emulation is no faster at all than the ARM images.

I do have HAXM installed, and on starting the emulator a message appears suggesting it's running in "fast" mode, but it's certainly not fast!

Is this because my PC (Windows 7, Intel) is not compatible, or did I miss something? How do I check compatibility?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't aware I had to. Did I miss a step? What BIOS setting needs changing?

Comment: Just to check; you did enable GPU emulation as it states in the installation instructions?

Comment: Same thing in 2016 with Android Studio default install and x86 Nexus (Google API) image, on a top of the range i7... Will report back when I find a solution. For now I'm just using my attached device... which BTW the default install doesn't make available either... SIGH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html):

> The software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT) support

However, this is not necessarily enabled by default on every machine with a VT-capable CPU. Once again, quoting the documentation:

> Virtualization extensions are typically enabled through your computer's BIOS and are frequently turned off by default. Check the documentation for your system's motherboard to find out how to enable virtualization extensions.

So, for example, on a Dell Latitude E6400 sitting to my right, there is a BIOS option for "Enable Intel Virtualization Technology" that you have to check.

Comment: I've confirmed that the BIOS is set so virtualisation is enabled. I can also see that the emulator, on start, shows a message that the HAXM is running and running in "fast mode", so I can only assume that virtualisation on this particular PC is not very fast (A Lenovo ThinkCentre FWIW). I'll mark your answer as the solution as I fully expect for most people it will be.

Comment: @OllieC, I don't know about that. I've seen HAXM working correctly, and in my case it made the emulator faster than a physical phone. It was that fast. [Intel also confirms this by saying](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/10/20/how-to-ensure-you-are-using-intel-haxm-for-android-emulator): `You can always visually see the difference in performance with HAXM and without. It is unmistakable`. However, on my main computer, which has a Q6600 CPU, HAXM still says it's running in "fast mode", but there's no noticeable difference, like in your case, so I think there's a problem with HAXM.

Comment: Down-voted because he already said HAX is reporting it's working in "fast" mode, suggesting VT was already enabled in the BIOS. He then confirmed this to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the 'use host GPU' option in AVD properties seems to make it a bit faster for me (still slow but usable).

**In Eclipse:** `Window > android Virtual Device Manager > Choose your device > Edit >` 'use host GPU' checkbox at bottom.

NOTE: If you are using laptop with nvidia hybrid graphics (GeForce G210M in my case) make sure you have it on high performance before running the emulator. Otherwise Virtual device wont find the graphic card and will crash.

Also apart of "Virtualization Technology" I enabled something called "VTd support" in BIOS. I have no idea what it is or what it does (no description in my BIOS) but either of the above mentioned actions fixed the issue for me

Comment: No idea why not upvoted, enabled host gpu and it runs like a beast now!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. After making sure everything is properly configured: 
(VT enabled in BIOS), Intel HAXM driver installed successfully, AVD details are as they should be.The emulator runs even slower than the ARM one.

If you still face the same problem as well. Star the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38486#c1)

Answer (score 1):

Go into the AVD Manager (one of the little Android icons in the toolbar, hover to see which one) and on your AVD change the Memory Options: RAM to 768 MB. Hardware acceleration seems to fail if it's bigger.

(Also make sure "Use Host GPU" is ticked!)

(And also note the messages just below that. You might have to go into the SDK Manager and install an image.)

It still boots up slow, but once it's been running for a minute or two it should be faster. But it's still not as fast as a clean, native device, attached via USB.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created and started several x86 emulators on an Linux server(cent os 7), and they all running slowly as hell.

The reason is, by default the emulators are set to have 2 cores, which is far less than the modern cell phones. So I changed the `config.ini` file in each emulator's directory, add one line `hw.cpu.ncore=6`(Depends on your major hardware, other properties may affect are `hw.ramSize`, `vm.heapSize` and so on. You can see all properties from `hardware-qemu.ini` in same directory.), and restart the emulators.

The emulators are running much more faster, not too much slower than real phones.

Hope my poor English expresses this clearly.

Answer (score -1):

In my case i have a SSD Samsung 850 pro with software Samsung magician with rapid mode on that was the problem I put it off and android emulator run as a fash again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer